# How do I get a moment.js date object with nothing but a time?

Tags: javascript, date, momentjs

The only time data I have is `7:00pm ET` -- I need to format this into a moment date object for the current day so I can then output other formats using `.format(...)`

I tried this:

```
moment.tz(new Date('7:00pm ET'), 'America/New_York');
```

I also tried:

```
moment.tz('7:00pm', 'America/New_York');
```

But that throws an error about not being a proper date string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to specify the format of the *input* string.

```
var m = moment.tz('7:00pm', 'h:mma', 'America/New_York');
```

However, if you're only doing formatting, then you probably don't need to worry about the time zone.

```
var m = moment('7:00pm', 'h:mma');
```

You can then do formatting from there, by calling `m.format("...")` substituting `...` with whatever *output* format you want.

Also note that just because `ET` is part of the input string doesn't mean that it can be recognized as US Eastern Time.  In general, time zone abbreviations are just too ambiguous to be used as input.

Comment: Matt is right, but note that this probably won't behave as expected if the target machine's current date is different than the date in the target time zone. It is currently 2016-05-15 in the 'Asia/Magdan' timezone, but ``moment.tz('7:00pm', 'hh:mma', 'Asia/Magadan').format()`` results in "2016-05-14T19:00:00+11:00". Might not be what you want.

Comment: Maggie has a good point. It's not the same date everywhere in the world at the same time.

Comment: I feel like this behavior could potentially be called a bug. The timezone is known. As such, why wouldn't we default the date to the date in the known timezone? Not sure how to change with good old ``updateOffset`` as it is though.

Comment: You should add an example like this to the docs. I could not find one.

Answer (score -1):

The easiest way would be to set up a moment to the current time with `var now = moment();` and then set that moments time with `now.set('hour', 19)`.